# Database Statistics Timer Job got hangs on initialized state

Tags: administration, timer-jobs, content-database

Env:

MOSS 2007 SP2 64 bit architecture, 4 wfe and1 app server, wins server 2003, Sql 2005 .

I have a site collection in web app which is reached 50 GB.  Due to this, the Site collection is not opening. All other Site collection are opening well excepted this one with 50 GB database. All Site collection in this Web app has their own Content Database.

I have checked the Timer job status and the Database statistics for the Web app having this Site collection is hangs on 50% initialized and this is happening for only one particular server "Server 4" instead of other 3 servers.

If i follow this steps on Server 4:

1. Stop Windows SharePoint Services Timer on Windows Services
2. Go to ‘C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config’ on front-end server
3. Clear xml files from the above folder.
4. Open cache.ini file and restart the number into ‘1’
5. Start Windows SharePoint Services Timer on Windows Services

it aborted the timer Job and the Site collection start working and everything is fine.

I have changed this timer Job to scheduled on Sunday. and i have the issue after this timer jobs runs and hangs on some X% to initialized.

How can i avoid this initialized situation?

Does anyone know How long it will take to finish this Job?

Is there any changes i have to make on the Web.config or iis website?

Is there any issue if i stop this timer Job?

Please give me some inside for this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Aniket